# Azure table storage - WADPerformanceCounterTable won't clear

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm working on some code to deal with diagnostics in Azure. I'm surrently running locally but have found that my WADPerformanceCounterTable wont seem to clear or finish any queries I make. It look slike its full of data as there is perf counter data from a couple of weeks ago and everything since.

What is an easy way to delete the rows in this table to let it start afresh? I tried the Reset button on the Storage emulator but that doesnt seem to do anything.

Lates thing I tried was the command DSInit /forceCreate - this seems to have deleted the table but I now cant get it back.

What should I have done / be doing?

thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1):

DSInit /forceCreate reinitializes that database used by the Storage Emulator. Running this will eliminate all existing data in your Windows Azure Storage Emulator (Tables, Blobs & Queues). Your Windows Azure Service that is using Windows Azure Diagnostics will recreate the WAD* tables at run-time.